# React Material-UI state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I'm new to React and trying to build a simple AppBar with a drawer using material UI.

The appbar and drawer seem to be implemented correctly, but for some reason the drawer state is not being updated when clicking the toggle button.

I've followed the references in material-ui as well as React, so I'm not sure what's going on. Here's the code for the component:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'
  import { Link } from 'react-router'
  import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
  import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
  import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';



  class Appbar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
      }

      handleToggle () {
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
        }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <AppBar
          title="Polism"
          onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
          />
          <Drawer open={this.state.open}>
            <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Menu Item </MenuItem>
          </Drawer>
          </div>
          )
        }

      }

  export default Appbar
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try `onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}`

Comment: @jpopesculian nope...still nothing

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Didn't see this comment before posting my answer - sorry!

Comment: @jpopesculian nope, no errors at all. Using the react dev tools as well, which shows everything should be fine

Comment: Do a little `console.log(this.state)` in your onLeftIconButtonTouchTap function

Comment: @jpopesculian it returns Object {open: false}

Comment: But when I check state inside of the toggle function it returns nothing... maybe for some reason the toggle isn't being called?

Comment: Your events not firing. That's the issue. I don't know why its not firing though :/ sorry man

Comment: @jpopesculian no worries, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do in order for your state to render correctly is to bind your function to the context. You can two this in three ways since your are using ES6 script.

1) Using Arrow Function

```
handleToggle = ()  => {
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
        }
```

2). Specifying the binding in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
        this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
      }
```

3) Binding while calling the function

```
render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <AppBar
          title="Polism"
          onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
          />
          <Drawer open={this.state.open}>
            <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Menu Item </MenuItem>
          </Drawer>
          </div>
          )
        }
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! But for some reason arrow functions are causing a Browserify error for me. Specifying the binding in the constructor or binding when calling the function didn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Its surprising for me that even after binding your open state doent mutate. Its works well for me though

Comment: Could it be an issue with react-router that i'm using?

Comment: Solved the issue. I completely forgot to inject the tap event plugin -.-, after that specifying the binder in the constructor fixed it completely. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help ! :) . Well you can you either of the binding method

Answer (score 0):

Since your `handleToggle` function relies on the correct context of `this`, you will need to bind it in your `render` function.

```
onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the handleToggle function in constructor as follows:
`this.handleToggle=this.handleToggle.bind(this);`